# Canon DSLR that changes aperture in Video

Tags: video, dslr

I purchased a 1100D/Rebel T3 as a starting DSLR.
I like the video aspect the most, but its quite limited.

I have some low aperture lenses and I like them very much, but they make it difficult to focus  when something is moving around.

The only option I have with this camera to change the aperture setting on video is... buying a different lens with a different minimum aperture.

I was wondering what Canon DSLR allows me to change aperture in video mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With canon the first DSLR that can do that is the 550d (you need to set the movie mode to manual in the settings otherwise it will adjust automatically).

However i would suggest something with a swivel screen (600d and up) because it's very useful while shooting video. The 60d and 7d have more options for video (frame rate for one) but it depends on your needs and budget if those are an option.

Hope this is helpful.